# column-izing data with HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a general solution using CSS to layout objects (buttons, text etc) in a tabular column format. What I'm having problems with is controlling the layout. CSS columns would be an answer but alas are not supported by IE9 and earlier.

How can I layout columns horizontally across the screen aligned with vertical-bottom? - with the inner-most div defining the width of the column, and it's parent div defining the spacing between each column.

Any advice or suggestions on this approach would be most welcome.

**Layout**

```
<--------------------> col3
<--------------------> col3
col1 <---------------> col3
col1 <--->  col2 <---> col3
col1 <--->  col2 <---> col3
```

**CSS**

```
.column { float:left; height:100px; display:table; }
.col {
    vertical-align:bottom;
    display:table-cell;
    margin-right:15px;  /* this does not work */
}
.coldata { width:20px } /* no spacing - element occupies total width of object */
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="column">
<div class="col">
    <div class="coldata">A1</div>
    <div class="coldata">B1</div>
    <div class="coldata">C1</div>
</div>
<div class="column">  
<div class="col">
   <div class="coldata">A2</div>
   <div class="coldata">B2</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Note the columns are aligned at the bottom and data is stacked vertically. Here is a  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/charstar/9xQ6S/4/).

Comment: Your question is what?  Your method appears to work.

Comment: IE10 has been rolled out to Windows 7 sometime last month. I'd just use whatever that supports. (Like [flexbox](http://html5please.com/#flexbox), although that still requires juggling the two somewhat incompatible specs until IE11.) CSS is otherwise flat out terrible at laying out things along the vertical axis first.

Comment: @millimoose That's a pretty irresponsible suggestion, considering Windows XP is the #2 most popular OS, which can't upgrade beyond IE8.  Plus, not everyone keeps Windows up to date.

Comment: @cimmanon Well, coddling WinXP users won't make them any less likely to upgrade though. Objectively speaking, this depends on what your target market is. People who don't upgrade OSes might not be customers it's worth pursuing. Personally if aiming for a broad, non-techie market, I'd just use a simpler layout (i.e. calling "this will be a pain on legacy IE" when presented with a design), or implement the complex one in  a way that degrades acceptably, instead of going for pixel perfection all the way back to 2006's state of the art in CSS support.

Comment: It works - but only when the width is specified in the inner most div. The width should be specified at the parent div `col`.

Comment: margins aren't applicable to `display:table-cell;`

Comment: Considering that 1% of the world still uses IE6 (crazy as it seems) limiting a web site to IE10+ would affect a sizeable audience.

Comment: @suspectus It's not really a website to IE10+, it's just showing people on IE9 and earlier a layout where buttons don't align horizontally.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. I guess I should be looking at `SVG` perhaps for effective control of columned data.

Comment: @millimoose ok but for the particular purpose I had in mind non-alignment would look awful.

Comment: @Salomonder As long as your "margins" are uniform around the elements in question, border-spacing effectively acts as margins around table-cells.

Comment: @cimmanon Yes, but he uses `margin-right:15px;`. Unfortunately IE<8 doesn't support border-spacing.

Comment: I don't understand the problem yet. Do you want to have the layout in http://jsfiddle.net/9xQ6S/6/ but using css tables?

Comment: IE<8 doesn't support `display: table` either, so the fact that they don't support border-spacing seems moot to me.

Comment: I've edited the question - sorry for the vague-ness.

Comment: Did I still misunderstand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using css tables for browsers that agree with the spec: http://jsfiddle.net/eZQGQ/.

The **columns** in the table model **are derived** from the presence of the cells. They don't exist: elements with `display: table-column` aren't drawn (= `display:none`). Look it up in http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#columns.

So the class `.column` is chosen unluckily. : )

You have to use inline blocks for old IE. Here is the hack:

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]><style>
  .column {
    display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    margin-right: 15px;
  }
</style><![endif]-->
```